# AJAX/JQUERY post and include

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, include

Find this confusing...

If a user fills in a contact form (contactus.php) and submits the form using AJAX/JQuery to (process.php) and on the (process.php) there is a include function but the PHP file isn't being included..

Why could that be??

LOL if it makes sense. All help would really be appreciated.

```
include("file_name_goes_here.php");
```

OR_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

How can I make (index.php) read a text file's contents as php coding and then excute it?

```
$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
```

Comment: What happens if you call `process.php` directly? Does it correctly include?

Comment: Can you post some more code, specifically the file that contains your include?

Comment: okay :) thanks i will post now

Comment: Would you know how to: make (index.php) read a text file's (data.txt) contents as php coding and then excute it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you load your txt file as a string and use [eval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)? Note: I'm not suggesting this is a good idea!

Comment: @user1037871: Because unless you are *absolutely sure* that the file you are `eval`ing is absolutely safe and isn't going to do anything bad, it could do something really bad. I wouldn't, for example, take any arbitrary file from a random user of your website and try to execute it.

Comment: No it's very safe :) Would you know how to do it?